# Valid state of electron systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, identical-particles

I would like to show that the state $|\psi \rangle = |\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\varphi_3 \rangle$ is not a valid state for 3 electrons (without spin) for $|\varphi_1\rangle,|\varphi_2\rangle,|\varphi_3 \rangle \in L^2$ and $\mathcal{H} = L^2 \otimes L^2 \otimes L^2$.

I tried to use the transposition operator to show that the function is symmetric (which would be a violation for fermions) but I'm not sure if thats a solid argument since it seems obvious that $P_{1,2}|\psi \rangle = |\varphi_2,\varphi_1,\varphi_3 \rangle \neq |\psi \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be symmetric to not be antisymmetric. The allowed antisymmetric state (in ket notation) is:

$$ \phi_{123} = \frac 1 6(
 |123\rangle +|231\rangle+ |312\rangle-
|321\rangle -|213\rangle- |132\rangle
)$$

and that is not $|123\rangle$.